# Live chat in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, user-profile

Does anybody have an idea on how to implement **live chat(One on one like facebook)** in sharepoint 2013 on-premise?

I have looked at https://www.cometchat.com/sharepoint-chat. It's close to what I'm looking for, but I want a ***free one*** $0 budget.

Assistance of any kind will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the SharePoint presence indicator and Skype For Business?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the basic edition of CometChat for $49. With CometChat, you get a whole lot of features at a very reasonable cost which includes audio video chat, one-on-one chat and moreover they do the integration for free.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You could [Integrate Yammer with on-premises SharePoint 2013 environments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270535.aspx) which is close to (but not the same) as facebook, with the posibility to use one on one chat.

[image]

Comment: I have checked on Yammer but i have not found  one on one private messaging feature

Comment: @NicholasSnr Down the right bottom you see an "Online Now" link. Expand it and select (or search) for a user to chat with

Comment: Wow! @Benny how can I achieve that on Microsoft 2013. Any tutorials?

Comment: @NicholasSnr Follow the link in the article on how to configure Yammer for SharePoint Server 2013 :)

Comment: let me try and see if it will work for me...

Comment: The chat feature is currently not showing in our company's yammer, has it been removed from Microsoft side??